# How can I align a table to the left in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This seems like a simple task but I've been running mad trying to align my table to the left handside of my page with bootstrap. I'm currently using flask to import my database which gets added to the html file as shown below.

No matter what I do, the tables are unaffected and remain in the centre of the page.

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content %}

<h1 align="center">Assist A Side</h1>

<div class="align-left-start">


<table class="table table-dark" name="Goalkeepers" id="tableStyle" align="right">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Positioning</th>
            <th scope="col">Handling</th>
            <th scope="col">Reflexes</th>
            <th scope="col">Average</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            {% for gk in goalkeepers %}
            <td>{{ gk.gkName }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.positioning }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.handling }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.reflexes }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.average }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-dark" name="Outfield">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Defending</th>
            <th scope="col">Passing</th>
            <th scope="col">Dribbling</th>
            <th scope="col">Shooting</th>
            <th scope="col">Stamina</th>
            <th scope="col">Average</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for player in players %}
            <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.defending }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.passing }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.dribbling }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.shooting }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.stamina }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.average }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HAsC.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs0On.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us a example of what you would like to accomplice even a small sketch of word layout

Comment: @WeyersdeLange Hi just added it now

Comment: Why aren't you using Bootstrap's rows and columns to hold your tables?

Comment: @j08691 I thought it'd be easier this way, I'll take a look into the rows and columns now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
} 

th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.a {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 180px;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>




<h1 align="center">Assist A Side</h1>

<div class="align-left-start">


<table class="a" name="Goalkeepers" id="tableStyle" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Positioning</th>
            <th scope="col">Handling</th>
            <th scope="col">Reflexes</th>
            <th scope="col">Average</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
           
            <td>{{ gk.gkName }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.positioning }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.handling }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.reflexes }}</td>
            <td>{{ gk.average }}</td>
        </tr>
       

    </tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<table class="a" name="Outfield">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Defending</th>
            <th scope="col">Passing</th>
            <th scope="col">Dribbling</th>
            <th scope="col">Shooting</th>
            <th scope="col">Stamina</th>
            <th scope="col">Average</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            
            <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.defending }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.passing }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.dribbling }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.shooting }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.stamina }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.average }}</td>
        </tr>
       

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this was perfect!